# Trying to save to Parent and child tables in Rails, but get argument error on nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Hi I am trying to save to two tables at the same time from one form. 
I have created `Contact` with a `has_many` relationship to `Order` which `belongs_to` `Contact`.

models/contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders,  reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

models/order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

I have also created the OrdersController which looks as follows

controllers/OrdersController.rb

```
    class OrdersController < ApplicationController
     def new    
        @contact = Contact.new
        @contact.orders.build
     end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(order_params)
        if @contact.save
            @order = @contact.orders.build(order_params)
            @order.save
            flash[:success] = "Your has been sent we'll get back to you shortly"
            redirect_to new_order_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "We were unable to process your request please try again or email admin@careerfalir.co.za"
            redirect_to new_order_path
        end
    end

    . . . 
    private 
        def order_params
            params.require(:contact).permit(:id,:name,:surname, :email, :comments, :dob, :phone_number, :contact_method, orders_attributes: [:email, :contact_id,:package,:jobs_strategy,:fast_turn_around,:order_comments, :contact_email])
        end
end
```

When I try and create and an order I get an error unknown attribute: name

```
    @contact = Contact.new(order_params)
    if @contact.save
        *** @order = @contact.orders.build(order_params) *** This is the line with the error
        @ordar.save
        flash[:success] = "Your has been sent we'll get back to you shortly"
        redirect_to new_order_path
```

Name does not exist in the Orders table which why I assume it is complaining, but it does exist in the Contacts table. Should I be creating this differently?

I have also tried `@order = @contact.orders.create(order_params)` with the same error.

Here is an sample of the view

```
  <%= form_for @contact, url: orders_path do |f| %>

        <div>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div> 
.....
  <%= f.fields_for :order do |order| %>
       <div> 
            <%= order.label :package %>
            <%= order.text_field :package, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
```

Comment: you have taken `@ordar.save` instead of `@order.save`, is that a typo?

Comment: this line  `@order = @contact.orders.build(order_params)` should be  `@order = @contact.orders.build` again `order_params` not needed while building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First point is the create method has `@ordar.save` instead of `@order.save` which I am assuming as **Typo**

2) The second point is `@order = @contact.orders.build(order_params)` this line does not require `order_params` and should be simply `@order = @contact.orders.build`

So with those changes your create action should be,

```
def create
    @contact = Contact.new(order_params)
    if @contact.save

        flash[:success] = "Your has been sent we'll get back to you shortly"
        redirect_to new_order_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = "We were unable to process your request please try again or email admin@careerfalir.co.za"
        redirect_to new_order_path
    end
end
```

Comment: My apologies that was indeed a typo.
That gets rid of the error and does save to the table it has however not taken any of the my argument for the Orders table

Comment: ok sry, no need to build the `order` again, check the updated answer.

Comment: @Jacques, checked my answer now?

Comment: I have tried with `@contact = Contact.new(order_params)
   if @contact.save` 
This is only saved to contacts table.
I also tried some other methods that gave me  **Unpermitted parameters :order**
I have since discovered that in my View I show the form using `f.fields_for :order`, while my association is `has_many :orders` and `accept_nested_attributes_for :orders`. If I change it to `f.fields_for :orders` it `@contact.save` works. So do other methods as well. Thanks  for you help. @Stravan

Comment: No mentions, good to see you solved your problem. Have a good day.